# highlightedSelections in PDFView osx

Tags: swift, macos, quartz-core, pdfview

The highlighted selections always appear in the same color even though I changed the color in PDFView (I am using OSX).
So I need to know why and how can I fix this bug?

```
pdfSelection.color = myColor //a color choise by user
pdfView.highlightedSelections?.append(pdfSelection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pdfSelection.color = myColor //a color choise by user
pdfView.highlightedSelections = nil
pdfView.highlightedSelections = [pdfSelection!]
```